# Users not receiving Windows 10 Packaged Flight

Tags: cordova, windows-store-apps, package, windows-10

I'm currently trying to use Windows 10 Packaged Flight system to beta test our Windows 10 Cordova application, following the [instructions found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-flights).

After the app package is certified, when I go into the Windows Store to download the packaged flight, it installs the production version of the app instead.

I have verified that both the login and Store credentials match the account included in Flight Group. I have also tried uploading the app as an .appxupload file as well as an .appxbundle file, and neither works.

Do I need to do something on the account to enable packaged flights? Is there something that would cause the app package not to be installed that I missed?

I am using Cordova v. 6.3.1, Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, and Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova 10.

[image: Windows 10 Package Information]

Comment: Did this ever get solved?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to do something on the account to enable packaged flights? Is there something that would cause the app package not to be installed that I missed?

Package flights will be published and available to the flight group immediately it passes certification. Thus, you don’t need to make any setting to enable it (unless you select manually publish or set publish date in the **Options** section). Please double check this in Dashboard first.

Also, please note that package flights can only be delivered to the following Windows 10 client builds: November 10586 & above for Desktop, February 10586.63 & above for Mobile. And you should ensure that your device family supported by your product version of app, because your Store listing info comes from your non-flighted submission. So you could check your device version.

Finally, I can think of is your email account. When you copy it directly into the group box, you might add extra characters, like space character, which might cause your account to be verified by mistake.

**Tips1**: You could try to create a new package flight and keep it (don’t have to delete the old one) with highest rank as the group member will get the highest- ranked package flight available to them. Please follow the guide [Package flights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-flights) to avoid something missed.

**Tips2**: In addition to package flights, you have other option that let you limit distribution of your app to only certain customers on Windows 10 device. You might as well try [gradual package rollout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/gradual-package-rollout), although it distributes packages to a random selection of your Windows 10 customer in a percentage specified by you.

Also, you could choose **hiding your updates package in the Store and using promotional codes** in Dashboard.

More details, see [Beta testing and targeted distribution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution).

Answer (score 1):

There might be a policy disabling package flight versions of Windows Apps.

You can check

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PreviewBuilds\AllowBuildPreview
```

If set to 0, package flight updates are not available for you.

Comment: What if there is no "PreviewBuilds" at all?

Comment: You just have to create that registry key

Comment: What is strange is that, another person in the group can see the flight, and there is no "PreviewBuilds" for them either. :/ Is there anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: Did you try to reset Store settings with wsreset.exe? And did you try logging in to the store on a different machine with that account that doesn‘t receive the flight?