# Windows App Store Package Flights not sending to Group

Tags: windows, uwp, package, windows-store-apps, windows-dev-center

I am trying to get a package flight to a client using the Microsoft Developer Portal.

According to the dev portal they should have access to it but nothing is available to update when they go to the Microsoft Store.

• The dev portal is showing that the appxbundle has successfully passed certification and is available in store.

• I have triple checked the email addresses and they are valid

• They are on windows OS build 15063.1029 version 1703

• I followed the tips here [Users not receiving Windows 10 Packaged Flight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000576/users-not-receiving-windows-10-packaged-flight) but nothing seems to have any effect

• The only kink is that they are on Windows 10 ENTERPRISE from HP, which definitely has some quirks but I am not familiar enough with windows to know if enterprise would mess with the app store version at all.

[image]

Comment: If you're sure that the app is in the store. You could open a support [ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support). You will get 1:1 support on that. Please kindly note that your support ticket will be free if it is Microsoft's issue.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, I tried to open a ticket and it linked me to stack overflow :( . I'll try again though, I can't seem to find my way past the automated support robot that doesn't lead to stack overflow when you try to select the topic of packaged flights.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it - like I already answerd here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533531

> There might be a policy disabling package flight versions of Windows
>   Apps.
>
> You can check
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PreviewBuilds\AllowBuildPreview
> ```
>
> If set to 0, package flight updates are not available for you.